# Is it possible to get the users who liked the instagram post using instagram graph api and python?

Tags: python, instagram-graph-api

Below is the code which we used to extract the userinfo.

def getMediaLikes( params ) :
""" Get insights for a users account

```
API Endpoint:
    https://graph.facebook.com/{object-id}?fields=likes.summary(true)&access_token={access-token}
    
Returns:
    object: data from the endpoint
"""

endpointParams = dict() # parameter to send to the endpoint

endpointParams['fields'] = 'likes.summary(true)' # period
endpointParams['access_token'] = params['access_token'] # access token

url = params['graph_domain'] + object_id  # endpoint url

return makeApiCall( url, endpointParams, params['debug'] ) # make the api call
```

But the above code is giving error:

{'error': {'message': '(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (reactions) on node type (ShadowIGMedia)', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'ACiWMzqRHhPHYygSK5PO4ge'}}

Can somebody help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

im currently working on a project with similar problems, my approach to this problem was not to use the instagram api but instead to go to instagram.com, open my requests analyzer and understand wich requests to make to get the infos i want. Maybe you can use this approach (this way of doing things is a bit harder to use than an API but you have no limits with it).
What i would do is asking for the list of users that liked the post by copying the request my browser send when i'm doing it by hand (clicking on the list of persons that liked the post), be aware that you will need to manage the cookies instagram gives you in most cases.
I think there might be a way of doing this with the API but if there isn't... you can still do this to extract the list of peoples that liked a post.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Our project requirement is to extract the data using graph api.